# customizing bootstrap columns in portrait orientation for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Task: Trying to make a mobile webpage: http://jsfiddle.net/anujbhai/hgaH7/3/ (also include jQuery & Bootstrap files in order to run properly).

Problem: Page should change layout according to Orientation - in landscape mode

```
<div id="videoThumbs">...</div>
```

will show 2 thumbnails and snaps beneath the

```
<div id="billboard">...</div>
```

while in the portrait mode the latter goes to the left of the screen and the former now shows only one thumbnail, appearing like a sidebar.

This is very hard to do with just mediaqueries and Bootstrap. I can't figure out a proper logic to be applied via JavaScript. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the default Bootstrap responsive utility classes.

Take a look at the documentation:

- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes
- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Small and Extra small devices classes can work for portrait tablet view and Small and Medium devices classes can works for landscape mode, you need to try various combinations.

Obviously, depends on the screen size of the tablet, but this works excellent in 7" and 9" tablets.

Comment: Bootstrap's responsive grid works according to the resolution of the device. What I am trying to do is change layout in mobile devices according to the orientation of the device. No matter what the resolutions of the device may be, it should change, when flipped to portrait from landscape, or vice-versa. So far I have figured out that this is out of the scope of Bootstrap. It is easier to do by mediaquery, but takes longer to incorporate the thumbnail view as generated by Bootstrap. I am opting for various combinations, and for this purpose i might need help in coding JavaScript.

Comment: The only method in JavaScript to _detect_ device orientation is with the screen resolution. Only in frameworks like Apache Cordova, you can access more methods using JS relative to device hardware.